# Allow user act as root, so he does not need to use sudo each time?

Tags: sudo, root, permissions

I wish for a user to have root privileges, but editing the /etc/sudoers file to allow no password still requires me to use the `sudo` command before a program I wish to run with elevated privileges .

I do I effectively make a normal user root without    being root so I have a structured home folder?

Comment: Why not have the user SU to root instead of using sudo?

Comment: @Tom, will not all files I save be written under root (root's ownership) then and not the current user?

Comment: The real answer here is **don't do that**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this is a bad idea, however if you really require this, then modify the following in /etc/sudoers:

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
<username>    ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
<username>      ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Or you can just use vipw and set the uid to be 0 for that username.

Answer (score 2):

If you do:

sudo su -

you will run 'su' with root permissions (elevated via sudo) and the trailing - means that you will use root's environmental variables, not your own.